# Content-Security-Policy: Difference between Google Chrome, Firefox, and Microsoft Edge

Tags: content-security-policy

I'm new to Content-Security-Policy headers, and I've been trying to define our policy to get our app working correctly.

I'm a Google Chrome user, and under Google Chrome, everything seems to be fine.  But, under Firefox or Edge, I see something like this:

> CSP14309: Unknown directive 'script-src-elem' in
>   Content-Security-Policy - directive will be ignored.

Why would `script-src-elem` be unknown in Edge and Firefox, but work correctly in Google Chrome?

What, exactly, is `script-src-elem`?

Help?

Comment: Why did I get -2 on this question?  I don't see a problem with it......

Comment: The browsers are being obtuse about this, your question makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a new CSP 3 policy that has so far only been implemented in Chrome, and a handful of smaller browsers (e.g. Opera).

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src-elem#Specifications

Comment: Great response, thanks!   My Google-Fu must be lacking.  I was unable to find much of anything for 'script-src-elem'.

Comment: MDN is a great resource